# How to write a tag wiki excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm hoping to establish some sort of guideline for writing tag wiki excerpts (or usage guidance).

Examples of tag wiki excerpts I find usually fall into two categories. The first references the tag itself:

- Use this tag for questions about [tag], which is [definition] (ie. [type-theory](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-theory))
- For questions about [tag] (ie. [agda](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agda))

While the second directly defines the tag:

- [tag] is [short definition] (ie. [coq](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coq))
- [tag] is [long definition] (ie. [category-theory](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory),[cubical-type-theory](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubical-type-theory))

I find the first option somewhat redundant and unhelpful (I'm guilty of having written multiple). I also feel that having a long definition is not necessary, as someone using the tag should already know its meaning. So perhaps definitions should only be used to disambiguate with other tags.

Some other remarks:

- Sometimes the phrase "Do not/only use this tag if ..." appears -- I think this is useful if the tag is prone to being misused
- references to other tags should be written as `[name]` rather than `[tag:name]`, as the latter does not render properly in wiki excerpts

I'd like to know what are some guidelines we could adopt for writing and editing tags in the future? (I'm not suggesting we rewrite all tags to fit into a single format)

Comment: It is correct that we need **our own** guidance, but here are the general principles that are advisable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188528/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123759/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264590/282094 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337/3648282 --- Also, the excerpt should contain the most useful and complete description within the shortest possible first sentence; for the pop-up.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the links, exactly what I was looking for!